# Convert a partial view to HTML 2019

Tags: c#, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Been at this for weeks. Something simple has become beyond difficult for no reason. All I want to do is return the HTML of a partial view. Why?

Rendering multiple partial views on one page in Azure is beyond slow. It causes a 502 error and you can't change the timeout (Thanks Microsoft).

Everything works in dev on my local, move to Azure and this one MAIN thing does not work. I have tried ALL the examples found.

The thing is the code and method seems to change with the framework. And nothing is newer than 2018. So either no one got this work and/or partial views are basically useless. This is closest I have come but the RazorViewEngine does not want to resolve.

```
private async Task<string> RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{

    RazorViewEngine _viewEngine = new RazorViewEngine();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = _viewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, false);

        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
            ControllerContext,
            viewResult.View,
            ViewData,
            TempData,
            writer,
            new HtmlHelperOptions()
        );

        await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

        return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made this class:

```
public class ViewRenderService
{
    private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private readonly HttpContext _http;

    public ViewRenderService(IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine, ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IHttpContextAccessor ctx)
    {
        _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _http = ctx.HttpContext;
        _http.RequestServices = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(RouteData routeData, string viewName, object model)
    {
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(_http, routeData, new ActionDescriptor());

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);
            // For views outside the usual Views folder
            if (viewResult.View == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
            }
            var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
            {
                Model = model
            };
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(actionContext, viewResult.View, viewDictionary, new TempDataDictionary(_http, _tempDataProvider), sw, new HtmlHelperOptions());
            viewContext.RouteData = _http.GetRouteData();
            await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

You can add it to `IServiceCollection` as `Scoped`.